# using database connection in other class Java

Tags: java, mysql, connection

I am new in java developing and I would need some help. I read that I can use a singleton class for making the connection to a database. I made this singleton connection, but I already didn't know how I can use this class in an other class. 
This is my connection:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class SingletonDBConnection {

private static SingletonDBConnection instance = null;
private static Connection conn;

private SingletonDBConnection() {

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName = "root"; 
    String password = "MyNewPassword";
        try {
                Class.forName(driver);
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName, password);
                }

                    catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfErr)
                    {cnfErr.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch(SQLException err)
                    {err.printStackTrace();
                    }
}


public static SingletonDBConnection getInstance() {
if(instance == null)
return new SingletonDBConnection();
else
return instance;
}

public static Connection getConnection() {
    return conn;
}
}
```

Now how can I use this connection in other classes?

The other class should be for example:

```
public class statement1 {
String sql = "CREATE TABLE test1 (test2 Integer)";
PreparedStatement pmst = conn.prepareStatement (sql);
rs = pmst.execute();
}
```

Comment: Look up singleton again. How do you use one?

Comment: sry I really don't know what you mean. My english is not that fluent :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// create and get instance of your Singleton
// then retrieve connection initialized in its private constructor
Connection conn = SingletonDBConnection.getInstance().getConnection();
PreparedStatement pmst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
...
```